# Check Whether a Web Application is Up or Not

Tags: linux, shell, unix, web, monitoring

I would like to write a script to check whethere the application is up or not using unix shell scripts.

From googling I found a script `wget -O /dev/null -q http://mysite.com`, But not sure how this works. Can someone please explain. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: not sure why it is voted down...

Comment: are you looking for monitoring systems like nagios or icinga https://www.icinga.org ?

Comment: Nope, I will send a simple mail with some recent logs if that URL doesn't respond anything. But I'm not sure how long time this command would wait for the response?

Comment: wget can handle timeouts (the **-T** option).

Comment: It would be good if I know the default timeout

Comment: Got it Thanks, time out is 900 secs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run the `wget` command
2. the `-O` option tells where to put the data that is retrieved
3. `/dev/null` is a special UNIX file that is always empty. In other words the data is discarded.
4. `-q` means quiet. Normally wget prints lots of info telling its progress in downloading the data so we turn that bit off.
5. `http://mysite.com` is the URL of the exact web page that you want to retrieve.

Many programmers create a special page for this purpose that is short, and contains status data. In that case, do not discard it but save it to a log file by replacing `-O /dev/null` with `-a mysite.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you can connect to your web server.

1. Connect to the port where you web server
2. If it connects properly your web server is up otherwise down.
3. You can check farther. (e.g. if index page is proper)

See this shell script.

```
if wget -O /dev/null -q http://shiplu.mokadd.im; 
then 
    echo Site is up
else 
    echo Site is down
fi
```